# Laravel: sorting posts by month

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

So I want to sort all posts by month, some kind of posts history by months, for this I want to use the `created_at` field of my `Post` model, how could I achieve this?

This is my posts migration:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('body');
    $table->string('image')->nullable();
    $table->boolean('isVisible')->default(true);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is my method controller where I want to gather all posts inside each month variable, don't know what database query should I perform to do this tho...

```
public function posts_by_month()
{
    $january = Post::;
    $february = Post::;
    $march = Post::;

    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'All posts gathered by month',
        'january' => $january,
        'february' => $february,
        'march' => $march,
        /* ... */
    ]);
}
```

This is jQuery code, where I append the results to each respective posts month container:

```
$.ajax({
  async: true,
  url: '/posts-by-month',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data) {
    $(".history[data-link='january']").append(generateHtml(data.january));
    $(".history[data-link='february']").append(generateHtml(data.february));
    $(".history[data-link='march']").append(generateHtml(data.march));
    $(".history[data-link='april']").append(generateHtml(data.april));
    /* ... */
  },
  error: function(data) {
    var errors = data.responseJSON;
    console.log(errors);
  }
});

function generateHtml(data) {
  var post_template = '';

  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
    post_template += '<div style="width:auto; height:auto; display:flex; align-items:center; margin:5px 0px; margin-left:30px;">';
    post_template += '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); font-size:4px; margin-right:5px;"></i>';
    post_template += '<a href="" style="font-size:15px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);">' + item.title + '</a>';
    post_template += '</div>';
  });

  return post_template;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be simpler to `ORDER BY created_at` in the query and then chop the results up with a simple loop either in PHP or probably javascript

Comment: Witch fields do you want to retrieve from DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format every row's `created_at` value as the month and then when your date retrieved from DB, sort them based on the month if you want.

```
$posts = Post::selectRaw("title, body, image, isVisible, date_format(created_at, '%M') month")
         ->get()
         ->sortBy('month');
```

Now in every post's model, you have another field named `month`.

Answer (score 0):

Use groupBy in collections:

```
public function posts_by_month()
{
    return Post::all()->groupBy(function($post) { // Get all posts as collection and apply groupBy method
        $post->created_at->format('F'); // ex: September
    });

    // {'September':[{'id':1, ...}, {'id':2, ...}], 'December':[{'id':3, ...}, {'id':4, ...}]}
}
```